# R Contrast coding in lmer output interpretation

Tags: r, lme4

I want to see if four predictors ("OA_statusclosed" "OA_statusgreen" "OA_statushybrid" "OA_statusbronze") have an effect on "logAlt." I have chosen to do a lmer in r to account for random intercepts and slopes by variable "Journal".

I want to interpret the output so that a higher OA status (in order of highest status: green, hybrid, bronze, closed). In order to do this, I have contrast coded the four variables as such (adhering to the order of the variables in my df being hybrid, closed, green, bronze):

```
contrasts(df$OA_status.c) <- c(0.25, -0.5, 0.5, -0.25)
contrasts(df$OA_status.c)
```

I have ran this analysis:

```
M3 <- lmer(logAlt ~ OA_status  + (1|Journal), 
              data = df,
              control=lmerControl(optimizer="bobyqa", optCtrl=list(maxfun=2e5)))
```

And got this summary(M3):

```
Linear mixed model fit by REML. t-tests use Satterthwaite's method ['lmerModLmerTest']
Formula: logAlt ~ OA_status + (1 | Journal)
   Data: df
Control: lmerControl(optimizer = "bobyqa", optCtrl = list(maxfun = 2e+05))

REML criterion at convergence: 20873.7

Scaled residuals: 
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-3.1272 -0.6719  0.0602  0.6618  4.4344 

Random effects:
 Groups   Name        Variance Std.Dev.
 Journal  (Intercept) 0.08848  0.2975  
 Residual             1.49272  1.2218  
Number of obs: 6435, groups:  Journal, 7

Fixed effects:
                  Estimate Std. Error         df t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)        2.03867    0.15059   18.27727  13.538 5.71e-11 ***
OA_statusclosed   -0.97648    0.09915 6428.62227  -9.848  < 2e-16 ***
OA_statusgreen    -0.74956    0.10320 6429.65387  -7.263 4.22e-13 ***
OA_statushybrid    0.04621    0.12590 6427.44114   0.367    0.714    
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Correlation of Fixed Effects:
            (Intr) OA_sttsc OA_sttsg
OA_sttsclsd -0.640                  
OA_statsgrn -0.613  0.934           
OA_sttshybr -0.501  0.763    0.744
```

I interpret this to mean that, for example, OA_statusclosed results in an average of -0.97 less of a logAlt value than the reference value, and that OA_statusclosed is a significant predictor.

I have two questions:

1. Am I approaching contrast coding correctly— in that, am I making "OA_statusgreen" my reference value (which is what *I think* I need to do?)
2. Am I interpreting the output correctly?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hi! Seems like your question refers mostly to know how about an statistical method, might be a better fit for https://stats.stackexchange.com/ 

You can share your code there too, as R is a everyday tool for statistical work.

Comment: Great— thank you so much for this insight into where to direct this question!

Comment: Your question will probably be moved to Cross Validated as @Juan Bosco inferred. That being said, you may find [this](http://bayes.acs.unt.edu:8083/BayesContent/class/Jon/Benchmarks/LinearMixedModels_JDS_Dec2010.pdf) to be a good resource for your question. [This Q&A](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/56600/correct-interpretation-of-lmer-output) may also be helpful. [Another potentially helpful Q&A.](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/532610/interpreting-interactions-in-linear-mixed-effect-model-using-lmer)